# How do I remove multiple uv coords?

Tags: uv, vertices, edges

**The problem:**

I have a 3d model and have uv unwrapped it. The vertices have multiple uv coordinates, which the exporter that I am using does not support.

---

**Examples:**

An object with multiple uv coords vertices.

[image: An Icosphere has been unwrapped. The UV map is 42 separated triangles.]

The object in game, the exporter and the engine cannot split edges or use multiple uv coordinates. In the image the uv coords have been merged together into a visual mess.

[image: UV coords have been merged together into a visual mess.]

An example of the uv map after a roundtrip: export from Blender and then import into Blender.

[image: A uv map mess.]

---

**Question:**

So is there a way in Blender to remove multiple uv coords vertices? The tool or addon I should use or a script in python would be appreciated.

---

**Extra details:**

If there is a tool in Blender that can do it, this is how it may work:

1. Select model that has multiple uv coords vertices.
2. The tool finds each connecting edge with multiple uv coords vertices and splits it. Or marks the edge as a seam.

This is my method to manually remove them:

1. Visually find uv seams and select edges.
2. Split the edges.

Comment: What is the issue? The "visual mess" looks like the result of that UV over a generated grid.  Can you provide a picture of result ot that UV in blender?.  It's my understanding that a vert will have a UV for each face it belongs, regardless of these all having the same UV location.  Could use the  default UV created with the icosphere instead.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that the uv map is messed up. I have added an example to the question.

The models that I create I edit the uv maps by hand.

Comment: do u mean multiple uv-maps? If so: Object Data Properties > UV Maps > minus Button

Comment: No, there is a single uv map. In the example, the vertices have multiple uv coordinates.